# Ajax remote validate wordpress username and email with Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to implement the following

[Ajax remote validate wordpress username and email with Jquery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058899/ajax-remote-validate-wordpress-username-and-email-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

The solution is showing proper messages but it does not allow to submit form as in both the cases whether the input is valid or not, it adds an error class.

Please help me to figure it out.

JQuery Validation Code:

```
$("#sign-up-form form").validate({
                rules: {
                   "log": {
                        required: true,
                        remote: {
                                url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                                type: "post",
                                data: {
                                   'user_email': function() {
                                        return $( "#log" ).val();
                                    },
                                   'action': 'check_user_name'
                                }

                            }
                    },
                    "user_email": {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                          remote: {
                                url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                                type: "post",
                                data: {
                                   'user_email': function() {
                                        return $( "#user_email" ).val();
                                    },
                                   'action': 'check_user_email'

                                }
                            }
                    },  
                    "phone1": {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    } 
                }
});
```

Wordpress Functions:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user_email', 'check_user_email_callback' );
function check_user_email_callback() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
if(email_exists($_POST['user_email'])){
    echo json_encode('Already registered');
}
else{
    echo json_encode('true');
}
die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user_name', 'check_user_name_callback' );
function check_user_name_callback() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
if(username_exists($_POST['log'])){
    echo json_encode('Already taken');
}
die();
}
```

Comment: provide your code here so can help

Comment: @Bhumi It is the same code provided as answer in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058899/ajax-remote-validate-wordpress-username-and-email-with-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: try `$('#form').valid()` this will return true if the form is valid. another possibility is you may have passed a submithandler to validate  function and not doing anything inside it.

Comment: @Cerlin Thanks for the reply. Could you please elaborate your answer. The problem is
if(email_exists($_POST['user_email'])){
        echo json_encode('error.');
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode('true');
    }
Returns proper error message, but instead of showing true message it should allow me to submit form, but right now it is showing true message with error class added to the field

Comment: can you post your FULL jQuery validation code?

Comment: try adding `submitHandler: function(form){$("#sign-up-form form").submit()}` to the object which you are passing into `validate` function

Comment: @CerlinBoss Thanks for the help, but it is not working.

Comment: also in php if the condition is true then you should return `true` anything other than that is considered false i guess.

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes that is the problem returning true also throws an error.